# Vuetify - Changing default navigation-drawer width

Tags: html, vuetify.js

Apparently Vuetify has 300px as the default width for a navigation drawer.

Even if I change the initial width to be different

```
<v-navigation-drawer id="add-expense-menu" ... style="width: 325px">
```

the transform applied to hide the drawer is still 300px, so a part of it sticks out.

Is there a way to change the default width of this component?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't set the styles using inline CSS. Instead, make use of the [props made available to the component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#props), and bind your desired width to it, i.e.:

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-bind:width="325">
```

If you are familiar with shorthands, use `:width="325"` will work, i.e.

```
<v-navigation-drawer :width="325">
```

Comment: can we pass a %? I can't seem to get it to work. I want the width to be 25%

Comment: @Brad Nope. It assumes the measurement unit to be pixels. If you want it to be a percentage of something, calculate it using a computed property and return the value in pixels unit.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the component and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Percentage works now

Comment: @Brad percentage is valid, as per answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the width as a prop directly to v-navigation-drawer as of latest versions of vuetify. 
This allows, fortunately, the usage of percentage too:

```
<v-navigation-drawer width="325"> //pixels
<v-navigation-drawer width="25%"> //percentage
```

You can back this up in 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers